# Volley: TimeOutError

Tags: android, android-volley

i want to fetch some data from a URL and the server is very slow...
So whenever i use volley to get the data, I get `TimeOurError`,
Is there anyway i can handle for how long volley should try to get the data as the server is slow...It takes little time
and i also want to run this request constantly to check data, I plan to use Timer for it...Is it okay to use Timer for continuously checking data?

Here is my volley request for now...It works for other URL's

```
public void checkData() {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.i("Response",response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.i("Response",error.toString());
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
            map.put("deviceID","none");
            return map;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

and i need to call this functions continuously( inside app)

**UPDATE**

I used

```
tringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            30000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

and it worked, Now I want to make this request continuously in my app...What is the best approach for that?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094718/change-volley-timeout-duration)

Answer (score 2):

You can **setRetryPolicy** for controlling volly request timeout time.

```
stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
        YOUR_TIMEOUT_MS, 
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23487556/where-is-setretrypolicy-written-when-using-volley-for-android-development) Qus.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, requestURL, stringListener, errorListener);
        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                30000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        addToRequestQueue(request);
```

// this code will help to increase the time for volley request try it.

Comment: Thank you..it worked very well and now can you tell me what is the best way to call this request continuously inside app?

Comment: try to create a method to call volley with sending requestURL, string Listener and error Listener and call the method cont.

Comment: what will i achieve with that? Can you give a good example? by editing your answer

Answer (score 0):

add these 4 lines to increase the android volley time to 60 seconds

```
StringRequest myRequest
```

or

```
JsonObjectRequest myRequest
```

.

```
RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
myRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);

RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(myRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will help to increase the time for volley request try it.And solve Volley: TimeOutError

```
stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
    30000,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
));
```